# PHP Composer working in locally but not in root user (centos 7)

Tags: php, centos, composer-php

Please look into the screenshot. I'm not sure why composer is not working in root user. please help me. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245772/why-running-command-as-sudo-returns-command-not-found

Comment: Hi @Natha Pawar First of install composer in machine.Please check link how to install composer in centos https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-composer-on-centos-7.

Comment: @MayurPanchal read the question again

Comment: composer installed on the sshd machine is not in sudo's pre-configured `$PATH` list of directories. that's why i didn't work. click the above provided link to learn more